# Cannot scroll webpage content in Android webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to load up this webpage https://chat1a.livechatinc.com/licence/1051791/open_chat.cgi in webview on Android [HTC Desire Z] but I couldn't get it to scroll its content.

The scrollbar does not appear also when I used the Android web browser. The issue with that is am not able to show all the content of that webpage. I have tried different hacks, here is what my new layout looks like now.

The funniest thing, it works well in iOS/iPhone but not in Android !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<WebView
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:id="@+id/wvLiveChat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not putting a webview in a scrollview. There is plenty of documentation on why you should avoid doing this.